# A simple Racket terminal interaction

Tags: racket

I'm just starting learning Racket-lang, and I want to write a simple program that reads from the terminal, does something with the input and responds.

Here's that program in Python :

```
while True :
    l = raw_input()
    print somefunction(l)
```

How should I write the equivalent in Racket?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent of that program in racket would be this:

```
(for ([line (in-lines)])
  (displayln (some-function line)))
```

That's if you want to just print the results to stdout. If you want to use the results as a value to pass to some other expression, [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for_list_and_for__list%29) returns a list of those values:

```
(for/list ([line (in-lines)])
  (some-function line))
```

Which is much more useful, because that list can be used by other parts of the program. However, it doesn't give you the list until it can get the entire list, which only happens when it gets to eof (if the user types ctrl-D or the equivalent). In reality you might want a specific condition for the user to say "I'm done, this is all I'm going to type, at least for now." For that, you would use the same form with a `#:break stop-condition` clause:

```
(for/list ([line (in-lines)]
           #:break (string=? line "done"))
  (some-function line))
```

For more complicated interactions with the user, you might want to keep track of some state that changes as the user enters more stuff. In that case, you can use [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for%2Ffold%29), or you can use a recursive function that calls itself to ask for more input. A recursive function tends to be more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. That was very useful. I'm trying to use recursion because ... good FP reasons. And I want to take advantage of tail-call optimization, so I'm trying this : (define (main input data) 
    (displayln input)
    (main (read-line (current-input-port) 'any) data))
 
(main "START" data)

But, unfortunately it seems to terminate after the first input line. Any idea why?

Comment: That function keeps going for me. The pattern I've usually used is similar, but with `data` as the only argument (usually named something more specific). There's also usually a conditional to determine whether the input is valid or not before passing it to a helper function, which takes the current state and the input and returns the next state, which I pass to the recursive call. There's also usually some stopping condition based on the current state and/or the input.

Comment: Actually, you're right. It works fine in drracket. Where it's failing for me is with raco exe  which I guess is a separate issue. (Though quite mysterious) Yeah, "data" is just a placeholder for my question here ... that's really the "state" of my application.

Comment: Explicitly writing a recursive function is a good way to start learning. Later? You can learn about named `let`, e.g. `(let loop [bindings] .... (loop))` which is just sugar for a function ("loop" is just a function name; you could name it otherwise). Even later? You can learn that the `for` macros expand to similar functional code you could write by hand -- it's not some sort of imperative looping feature built into Racket.