# Why this list has only void items in Racket

Tags: input, scheme, racket

I tried to have user input function using code on this page: [A simple Racket terminal interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192335/a-simple-racket-terminal-interaction/35193660#35193660)

```
(define entry_list (for/list ([line (in-lines)]
           #:break (string=? line "done"))
  (println line)))

(println entry_list)
```

Output is:

```
this 
"this "
is 
"is "
a 
"a "
test
"test"
for testing only
"for testing only"
done
'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

Why is the list consisting of only "void" items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `println` function returns `#<void>`. If instead of println you put something that returned a different value for each line you would end up with a more interesting list.

For example, the following code should return a list with the lines that you typed in:

```
(define entry_list
  (for/list ([line (in-lines)]
             #:break (string=? line "done"))
    line))
```

If you just want to print the lines then you could have used `for` instead of `for/list`, to avoid creating an useless list of voids at the end: